# In Makefile, how to cleanup lockfile files?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, onerror, lockfile

In GNU Make 3.81, I need to remove a lockfile in the event of an error in any part of the toolchain. Is there a special target that will allow me to do this? Do I need to write a wrapper script?

In the example below, I need unlock_id to happen if the rule for file.out fails.

Thanks!
-Jeff

```
all: lock_id file.out unlock_id

file.out: file.in
    file-maker < file.in > $@

lock_id:
    lockfile file.lock

unlock_id:
    rm -rf file.lock
```

Comment: An error in a particular command, or an error anywhere in the Make process?

Comment: Hi Beta, I updated the question with more detail. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do the lock/unlock in the same target as `file-maker`:

```
file.out: file.in
        lockfile $@.lock
        file-maker < $< > $@; \
        status=$$?; \
        rm -f $@.lock; \
        exit $$status
```

This executes the `file-maker` and unlock steps in the same shell, saving the status of `file-maker` so `make` will fail if `file-maker` fails.

Answer (score 4):

This is kind of a kludge, but it works:

```
all:
        @$(MAKE) file.out || $(MAKE) unlock_id
```

Comment: You can also spam this after any commands that might fail as an alternative to Beta's global solution. `./commandThatMightFail.sh || $(MAKE) unlock_id`

Answer (score 0):

You want the `.DELETE_ON_ERROR` target, which allows you to specify files to be deleted upon errors.

http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Special-Targets.html

**EDIT**

My bad, that's a half-truth. It allows you specify that you want files to be deleted, but as for which ones and under what circumstances, that's up to `make`.

Comment: Hi Chris,
I have a .DELETE_ON_ERROR, but the documentation indicates it works differently. It looks like it will delete $@ if the respective target fails, for all targets in the Makefile. That being said, I never really got the behavior of .DELETE_ON_ERROR to work as I expected…


".DELETE_ON_ERROR
    If .DELETE_ON_ERROR is mentioned as a target anywhere in the makefile, then make will delete the target of a rule if it has changed and its recipe exits with a nonzero exit status, just as it does when it receives a signal. See Errors in Recipes."

Thanks!
-Jeff

Comment: @Jeff: `.DELETE_ON_ERROR` works for me (GNUMake 3.81), but only if the name of the target is the name of the file. In your case, it looks as if the name of the target is `lock_id`, but the file you're trying to build (and want to delete) is `foo.lock`.